# Saved SharedPreferences changes lost when app is cleared from memory

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am updating and saving an array of values in SharedPreferences from within a Settings activity. Specifically, from an AlertDialog in an onCLickListener for a ListView. The changes seem to be saved fine - i.e. they are still intact after I close and re-open the MainActivity, but as soon as my app is released from memory and restarted the SharedPreferences revert to their previous state.

I read somewhere that calling editor.clear() before editor.commit() can prevent this happening, but this also has the effect of deleting all of the other values in my SharedPreferences (i.e. the ones that I am not editing in this code).

Can anyone explain why I am losing my SharedPreference updates, and how I can fix this?

The code is below:

```
final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_folders);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {

        // ListView Clicked item index
        int itemPosition = position;

        // ListView Clicked item value
        final String itemValue = (String) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);

        // Ask the user to confirm deletion of the item using an AlertDialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SourceFolders.this);

        builder.setTitle("Confirm");
        builder.setMessage("Remove " + itemValue + "?");

        builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Yes - remove the current item from SharedPreferences
                SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(SourceFolders.this);
                Set<String> set = prefs.getStringSet("source_folders", null);
                if (set == null) {
                    dialog.dismiss(); // List of folders in Preferences is empty - shouldn't happen
                }
                // Remove the selected item from the list
                set.remove(itemValue);
                // Update Shared Preferences
                SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
                edit.putStringSet("source_folders", set);
                edit.commit();
                folderlist = new ArrayList<String>(set);
                refreshListViewFromPrefs();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }

        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Do nothing
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Just a side note ; if __set == null__, which per comments shouldn't happen, you face a NPE right after the if clause. I.e dialog.dismiss() does not return from the method.

Comment: Thanks - noted. I should also say that this code is in a PreferenceScreen, and that I have other code in the same activity which also saves (adds) data to the same SharedPreferences item (source_folders), but which does not suffer from the same problem - i.e. items added to this Preference item in the other code do not get lost when the app is released from memory. ????

Comment: does the error still persist?

Comment: Yes I still have the error. I've had to implement an ugly workaround for now, which consists of reading all of my SharedPreferences into variables, calling .clear(), rewriting the Preferences from my variables, then calling .commit(). If I do this I no longer lose the changes when the app is released from memory.